# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, visual studio code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, visual-studio-code

my app was running normally , after running flutter upgrade it gives me this error . I didn't change anything in my code.
note: I am using visual studio code
I tried flutter clean, flutter upgrade but it gives the same error .
I checked JAVA_HOME path and it is okay

```
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.18.1/lib/src/picture_provider.dart:50:59: Error: No named parameter with the name 
'nullOk'.
        context != null ? Localizations.localeOf(context, nullOk: true) : null,
                                                          ^^^^^^        
../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/localizations.dart:413:17: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static Locale localeOf(BuildContext context) {
                ^^^^^^^^
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\mobileapps\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
                                                                        
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\mobileapps\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 49s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        50.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

this is the result of run doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at D:\mobileapps\flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (7 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hit-ham\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
rosoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • GM1910 (mobile) • bb671501 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.190

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update the package 'flutter_svg' from 0.18.1 to 0.19.3 and it should solve your issue,
it happens because of the 'nullOk' parameter that was removed in Flutter 2. You can read about it here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/eliminating-nullok-parameters

I found this solution and it worked for me

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer save my life. It was very silly problem but shown very big error. Thanks ones again